# Woocommerce REST API v3: Fetching multiple variations at once

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the woocommerce library for nodejs to fetch product data.
The app already has all the product and variation ids, I just need to periodically fetch prices for the **variations**. I know I can use `include: [ids...]` to fetch multiple products at once, but it doesn't work when fetching variations. I also know I can fetch all variations of a single product, but with the number of products to fetch this generates too many requests.

Is there a better way to get multiple variations, or just their prices, within one API request?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but there is no way to get all variations in one request.
You need to do a request for each variable product to get all variations that belong to that product.

To avoid too many requests you can add some sort of delay between each request so you don't get ratelimited if that's the problem.